# Derivation of Borel measures w.r.t a "bigger" measure?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, functional-analysis

Given two Borel measures $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ on $\mathbb R$, is there always a Borel measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb R$ such that

$$
d\mu_1=w_1 d\mu,\qquad d\mu_2=w_2 d\mu,
$$
for some functions $w_1$ and $w_2$ on $\mathbb R$ ?

Comment: I've updated the answer according to the comment by @GEdgar - you may be interested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, if both measures are $\sigma$-finite. Then for such measure to exist it should be s.t. $\mu_i$ are absolute continuous w.r.t. $\mu. $ Just take 
$$
\mu = \mu_1+\mu_2.
$$

If at least one of the measures is not $\sigma$-finite then as @GEdgar mentioned, there is a counterexample. Take $\mu_1$ to be Lebesgue measure and $\mu_2$ to be counting measure. Assume that measure $\mu$ exists, then

1. by considering $1=\mu_2(\{a\})$ prove that $\mu(\{a\})>0$ for any singleton set $\{a\}$;
2. by considering $1=\mu_1([0,1])$ prove that $w_1(x)>0$ in only countably many $x\in[0,1]$ (say, on the set $K$);
3. prove that $\int\limits_{[0,1]\setminus K} w_1(x)\mu(dx)= 0$ while $\mu_1([0,1]\setminus K) = 1$.

Comment: Well, he didn't say $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ are sigma-finite!  What if $\mu_1$ is Lebesgue measure and $\mu_2$ is counting measure (not sigma-finite).  Then $\mu = \mu_1+\mu_2$ I understand.  But what are $w_1$ and $w_2$?

Comment: @GEdgar: you're right. I was presuming that Borel measures are defined to be $\sigma$-finite, which is not the case. Does your example then a counterexample for the OP (I understand, that $\mu_1+\mu_2$ doesn't work in this case)?

Comment: Let Student answer that...

Comment: @GEdgar: thanks, I gave him some hints.

Comment: Thanks to everyone, that was indeed was I was looking for, that terrible measure counting the reals ...